# C++ class using a template

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I was implementing a short of simple-customize data structure of a graph in C++. The first "class" I implemented was "Node" or decorated node. After few research I moved from class to template, it was like this.

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:

Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
//Setters
void    heuristic       ( double heuristic )    {this->_heuristic=heuristic;}
void    visited         ( bool visited )        {this->_visited=visited;}
void    element         ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
void    incrementOrder  ()                      {this->_order++;}
void    decrementOrder  ()                      {this->_order--;}

//Getters
int     order           ()                      {return this->_order;}
double  heuristic       ()                      {return this->_heuristic;}
T       element         ()                      {return this->_element;}
bool    isVisited       ()                      {return this->_visited;}

protected:

double  _heuristic;
bool    _visited;
T       _element;
int     _order;

};
```

The problem came when it was time to implement the "Edge" class. I though of something like:

```
#include "Node.hpp"

template <typename T>
class Edge {
public:

Edge    (Node<T>& leftNode, Node<T>& rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;}    

Node<T> leftNode    ()                          {return this->_leftNode;}
Node<T> rightNode   ()                          {return this->_rightNode;}

void    leftNode    (Node<T> leftNode)          {this->_leftNode=leftNode;}
void    rightNode   (Node<T> rightNode)         {this->_rightNode=rightNode;}

protected:

Node<T> _leftNode;
Node<T> _rightNode;

};
```

That's it, the constructor is giving me problems and after research I believe is because of "Node" is not a real class and that made "Edge" be turned to a template too.

The question is ¿Is there anyway Edge could use this Node without be turned into a template?

Thank you for your time.

//Edit #1

I would like the implementation to be as general as possible, that's why I think the Edge class should have attributes type Node.

The main block is as follows:

```
int main(){

    Node<int> *n1 = new Node<int>(1);
    Node<int> *n2 = new Node<int>(2);

    Edge<int> *e = new Edge<int>(n1, n2);

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++11 -Iinclude/ src/Main.cpp -o exe/main
src/Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/Main.cpp:11:16: warning: unused variable ‘e’ [-Wunused-variable]
     Edge<int> *e = new Edge<int>(n1, n2);
                ^
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Edge<T>::Edge(Node<T>*, Node<T>*) [with T = int]’:
src/Main.cpp:11:40:   required from here
include/Edge.hpp:8:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node<int>::Node()’
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                     ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: constexpr Node<int>::Node(const Node<int>&)
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: constexpr Node<int>::Node(Node<int>&&)
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node<int>::Node()’
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                     ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: constexpr Node<int>::Node(const Node<int>&)
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: constexpr Node<int>::Node(Node<int>&&)
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Node<int>’ and ‘Node<int>*’)
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: Node<int>& Node<int>::operator=(const Node<int>&) <near match>
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘const Node<int>&’ [-fpermissive]
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate is: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int] <near match>
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]’
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: Node<int>& Node<int>::operator=(Node<int>&&) <near match>
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘Node<int>&&’ [-fpermissive]
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate is: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int] <near match>
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]’
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:69: error: conversion to non-const reference type ‘class Node<int>&&’ from rvalue of type ‘Node<int>’ [-fpermissive]
     Edge    (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=ri
                                                                     ^
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Node<int>’ and ‘Node<int>*’)
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: Node<int>& Node<int>::operator=(const Node<int>&) <near match>
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘const Node<int>&’ [-fpermissive]
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate is: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int] <near match>
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]’
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note: candidate: Node<int>& Node<int>::operator=(Node<int>&&) <near match>
 class Node {
       ^
include/Node.hpp:14:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘Node<int>&&’ [-fpermissive]
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note: candidate is: Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int] <near match>
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from include/Edge.hpp:2:0,
                 from include/Graph.hpp:1,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Node.hpp:17:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]’
     Node                    ( T element )           {this->_element=element;}
     ^
In file included from include/Graph.hpp:1:0,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
include/Edge.hpp:8:95: error: conversion to non-const reference type ‘class Node<int>&&’ from rvalue of type ‘Node<int>’ [-fpermissive]
     (Node<T> *leftNode, Node<T> *rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;
                                                                                       ^
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 1
```

Comment: "_Is there anyway Edge could use this Node without be turned into a template?_" Yes, if it specified the type for `Node`, that's stored (e.g. `Node<int>`, `Node<std::string`>, etc.).

Comment: What were the problems the constructor is giving you?

Comment: 1. Like @hegel5000 asked - what was the exact problem? 2. You're constructing Edge's using non-const references, is that what you actually want? Especially seeing how you pass nodes by values a lot? 3. Please post compilable code, and try removing the features irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Oh, nice, so that looks like Mihayl has your answer!

Comment: That error about the `Node` default constructor has nothing to do with templates. You would see essentially the same error if you removed the template parameters from both classes and replaced `T` with `int` or `std::string` or something everywhere else.

Comment: All your use of `this` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your members `_leftNode` and `_rightNode` need to be initialized but `Node` has no *default* constructor. Your current constructor do not initialize them but tries to assign them new values in the constructor body.

You can modify your `Edge` constructor to initialize them in its member-initializer list like this:

```
Edge(Node<T>& leftNode, Node<T>& rightNode):
     _leftNode(leftNode), _rightNode(rightNode)
{
}
```

Or you could add a default constructor to `Node` - one taking no arguments.

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    Node() = default;
    // ...
```

Additionally you can do the same with the `Node( T element )` constructor and use `const` reference where possible like `Node( const T& element )` and `Edge(const Node<T>& leftNode, const Node<T>& rightNode)`.

https://godbolt.org/g/R7MS4A

Comment: Your current constructor does not initialize them in a mem-initializer-list like the answer shows, it assigns to them after they've been constructed.  The difference between `MyClass::MyClass(Type arg) { member = arg; }` and `MyClass::MyClass(Type arg) : member(arg) {}` is like the difference between `Type obj; obj = value;` and `Type obj = value;`.  In both comparisons, the first uses a default constructor and then an assignment, but the second uses a different constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If your use case does not require information about `element` (e.g. writing generic algorithms that just walk a graph without having to access its node data) you could try separating the data from the rest of the interface. Here is the general idea:

```
#include <iostream>

// Note: don't do this
using namespace std;
```

Split off the node metadata to a non-templated class `INode`:

```
class INode {
public:
    void heuristic(double heuristic) { this->_heuristic = heuristic; }
    void visited(bool visited) { this->_visited = visited; }
    void incrementOrder() { this->_order++; }
    void decrementOrder() { this->_order--; }

    //Getters
    int order() { return this->_order; }
    double heuristic() { return this->_heuristic; }
    bool isVisited() { return this->_visited; }

protected:
    double _heuristic;
    bool _visited;
    int _order;
};
```

Create a templated wrapper to hold the data

```
template <typename T>
class Node : public INode {
public:
    Node(T element) { this->_element = element; }

    void element(T element) { this->_element = element; }
    T element() { return this->_element; }

protected:
    T _element;
};
```

If `Edge` does not need to know about `element`, it can use `INode`s instead.

```
class Edge {
public:
    //Edge    (Node<T>& leftNode, Node<T>& rightNode) {this->_leftNode=leftNode;this->_rightNode=rightNode;}
    Edge(INode leftNode, INode rightNode)
        : _leftNode(leftNode)
        , _rightNode(rightNode)
    {
    }

    INode leftNode() { return this->_leftNode; }
    INode rightNode() { return this->_rightNode; }

    void leftNode(INode leftNode) { this->_leftNode = leftNode; }
    void rightNode(INode rightNode) { this->_rightNode = rightNode; }

protected:
    INode _leftNode;
    INode _rightNode;
};
```

You can now use this as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Node<int> l(1);
    Node<int> r(2);
    Edge edge(l, r);
}
```

Please consider this as pseudo-code to demonstrate the idea - even though it compiles it has some issues with object slicing. You will want to make sure you have virtual classes and use (const) references.

Answer (score 0):

A templated class doesn't exist until you instantiate it with a specific type. Furthermore, a template `Node<int>` is a different type than `Node<char>`. If you want the Edge class to be able to handle a `Node` without the Edge class being a template class itself, you would either need to specify the Node type explicitly in the Edge class, like this:

```
Edge(const Node<int>& leftNode, const Node<int>& rightNode) { ... }
```

Or you would have to turn the Edge class into a template in order for you to be able to generically handle edges with nodes of different types.

Comment: Yea, was his question not how to use the node templated class in the edge class without the edge class being a templated class as well?

Comment: Well, that's what Roberto _thought_ his problem was after some initial research (before he posted the question).  But after revealing his compiler error (in an edit), the real problem turned out to be something completely unrelated to templates.

Comment: lol I think downvoting because I answered the question he asked is a little odd, but to each his own, I suppose